# How to insert data in child table from react to django rest framework models

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm new to React and Django rest framework. I want to insert profile data into the Django model using fetch API in react. I'm continuously getting response header as:

> {"user":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]}

I've checked by printing response on console, and it gives status code '200 OK'. But it didn't update the database as well.

My submit form function in react is:

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const profile = profileObj(selectedProfileImg, contact, city, country, address);
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile))
        let form_data = new FormData()
        // *************************
        // this is the foreign key in the model and it gives the problem.
        // *************************
        form_data.append('user',JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).id) // (foriegn key value) User added by signing up 
        form_data.append('profile_img', profile.prof_img)
        form_data.append('contact',profile.contact)
        form_data.append('city',profile.city)
        form_data.append('country',profile.country)
        form_data.append('address',profile.address)
        form_data.append('store_title','storename') // (foriegn key value) Data with this key exists in database
        form_data.append('cus_status',profile.cus_status)
        
        // *********************************
        // Also I want to know what the boundary means in content 
        // type. As I see it on google so I used it but removing it 
        // gives another boundary error.
        // *********************************
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/customer_apis/addCustomer/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
            },
            body: form_data
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                console.log(res.status)
                if (res.status !== 200)
                    document.getElementById('text-error').innerHTML = res.statusText
                else {
                    navigate('/create_store')
                }
            })
    }
```

My Django model is:

```
class CustomerData(models.Model):
    CUS_STATUS=(
        ('A','Active'),
        ('B','Blocked'),
        ('X','Blacklist')
    )
    # I imported the user as (from django.contrib.auth.models import User)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store_title=models.ForeignKey(StoreData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default='')
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    phone=models.IntegerField(default=00)
    profile_img=models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, blank=True,null=True)
    cus_status=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CUS_STATUS, default='A')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.store_title)
```

And Django API view is:

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def addCustomer(request):
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response("Success")
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

CustomerSerializer is:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerData
        fields='__all__'
```

How could I add data to the child table having foreign keys from React Apis to Django rest Framework?
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you add `CustomSerializer` into this post?

Comment: @DavidLu I added it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use some other field for uploading `user` and `store_title` data.

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only = True)
    store_title_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only = True) 
    user = UserSerializer(read_only = True)
    store_title = StoreTitleSerializer(read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerData
        fields=("user", "store_title", "city", "country", "address", "phone", "profile_img", "cus_status", "user_id", "store_title_id", )
```

And in frontend, you can upload `user_id` and `store_title_id` as the integer value.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    ...
    form_data.append('user_id', parseInt(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).id, 10)) 
    ...
    form_data.append('store_title_id', 1) # for example
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately doing this gives the error but it gives more errors.

Comment: can you show me the errors?

Comment: {"user":["This field is required."],"store_title":["This field is required."],"user_id":["A valid integer is required."]

Comment: did you add `read_only = True` in `user` and `store_title` ?

Comment: And I think now `user_id` was uploaded as string. Did you use `parseInt` function?

Comment: yes I've use parseInt like this  form_data.append('user_id',parseInt(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).id))

Comment: I think you need to make sure that value is a really integer in frontend.

Comment: I've added the read_only=True and now these errors are gone. But it gives me an internal server error "Column 'user_id' cannot be null". Also I've check the value at front end by printing it on console and it int value.

Comment: You can check out the validated data by adding `print(serializer.validated_data)` under the line `serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)`. 
Check if the validated_data has 'user_id' field actually.

Comment: WebKitFormBoundarySJ5LsOf75d8O4XLX\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_img"\r\n\r\nundefined\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySJ5LsOf75d8O4XLX\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="contact"\r\n\r\n1234567\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySJ5LsOf75d8O4XLX\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="city"\r\n\r\nLahore\r\n------

Comment: It gives the long output like this. I think the problem is with the boundary I've added with the content-type in the fetch api of react js. I've highlighted it with comments in the question's first code block. May you have a look there?

Comment: That's strange. Did you add the `user_id`, `store_title_id` in the fields?

Comment: Yeah I added it but could you look at the fetch api request? I think it's a boundary problem there. As I've just added it by searching on Google so don't know about it. Also removing it gives error of boundary

Comment: So now the user_id is saved correctly?

Comment: What is the problem now? Is `CustomerData` saved with errors?